# Magento var directory

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

Hi i am facing this error on my magento

```
Unable to find writable var_dir

#0 /home/glasses/html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options.php(66): Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options->getVarDir()
#1 /home/glasses/html/includes/src/Varien_Object.php(112): Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options->_construct()
#2 /home/glasses/html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Config.php(200): Varien_Object->__construct(Array)
#3 /home/glasses/html/app/Mage.php(739): Mage_Core_Model_Config->__construct(Array)
#4 /home/glasses/html/app/Mage.php(678): Mage::_setConfigModel(Array)
#5 /home/glasses/html/index.php(71): Mage::run('', 'store')
#6 {main}
```

currently i have httpd web server, and also i issue `chmod -R 777 var/` directory but the problems is still there. Other pages can be access except the front page.Thanks

Comment: the site url is https://www.glassesonline.com.my

Answer (score 0):

Currently on you site I can see the error - **cache_dir must be a directory**

To fix this issue - make a tmp dir in the root of the magento installation hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Magento checks tmp dir next way:

```
$dir = $this->getSysTmpDir().DS.'magento'.DS.'var';
        if (!$this->createDirIfNotExists($dir)) {
            throw new Mage_Core_Exception('Unable to find writable var_dir');
        }
```

As you can see, the piece of code is trying to create temporary directory in the system tmp directory. And if the creation process is failed - it throws an error. So, first of all, you should check the "tmp" dir exists in the system's root directory (/tmp) and php has enough rights to create/write into magento tmp dir there.